Azure Function App: No functions appearing in portal following publish
Detail:
.NET 8, isolated
All packages are current version, but have also tried with just a "template" version from the Function App CLI tools
Deployment is with the Function App and non-file share storage account deployment (so using the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE environment variable.
The Function App identity has Storage Blob Owner on the storage account.
Publishing is being completed via a Github action:
- name: Build dotnet Core Function App
  run: dotnet build -c Release
  working-directory: /home/runner/work/core/core/NetCore

- name: Publish dotnet Core Function App
  run: dotnet publish -o /home/runner/work/output/dotnet-fa /p:UseAppHost=false
  working-directory: /home/runner/work/core/core/NetCore

  - name: 'Upload Dot Net Function App'
    uses: Azure/functions-action@v1.5.2
    id: fa
    with:
      app-name: func-app-dotnet-${{ inputs.targetEnvironment }}
      package: '/home/runner/work/core/core/artifacts/dotnet-fa/.'

I can run up locally in VS (both Code and VS2022, as well as with DevContainers) absolutely fine, with no errors.  Absolutely no errors are logged (gone through all the trace logs etc) on Azure.
Checked in the file interface to see that the package does appear to be unpacked correctly, and the files are there as expected.
When I try and direct publish from VS2022, I get a popup that indicates the runtime needs to be updated; but nothing actually indicates what / where the update is being applied (not changes at all on the configuration of the Function App).
I'm pretty sure it HAS to be a configuration issue somewhere, but been beating my head off this for a few days, and without any logs pointing me at an error I haven't got a clue what to keep checking.

Have you confirmed that the function is running with runtime version ~4 in the Azure function configuration, Function runtime settings tab  ?

@Richard yup, AzureWebJobsDashboard__accountName, AzureWebJobsDashboard__accountName, FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION, FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION are all set.

Only thing I can suggest without having a peek, is go to Diagnose and solve problems on the left hand of the side panel, then configuration and management, Azure should then do some analysis for you and let you know what the issue is and then give you a suggestion on ways to fix it.

Make sure deploying artifact has host.json under the root folder. Also double check you have all the environment variables like runTimeStack, _Function_Version, _Function_RunTime etc. configured.
